# ASP.NET Core MVCについて、スキャフォールディングコマンドにて必ず失敗します。

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core MVC初学者です。タイトルの通り、スキャフォールディングができません。
以下のコマンドを実行すると、

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.;Database=testdb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

以下のエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

SQLサーバー自体は建っていて、Visual StudioからでもSQL Server オブジェクト エクスプローラーからではデータテーブルを閲覧できます。データテーブル名も"testdb"で正しいはずです。どなたかエラーの原因のわかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示ください。

Comment: `Server=.`の後にバックスラッシュ（\）入れるとどうなりますか？日本語環境だと￥かもしれませんが。

Comment: 同じエラーメッセージが出てしまいました…

Answer (score 0):

Serverの指定でホスト名(アドレス)の後にインスタンス名を明示してください。
例）localhost\SQLEXPRESS

インスタンス名はサービス管理ツール(windows)のサービス名から確認できます。
例）"SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)"

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio で接続できている時の、右下に表示されている接続の`プロパティ` ウィンドウの中の「`接続文字列`」の値と何が違うか比較してみてください。
何か気づく点があると思います。

[image: Visual Studio 接続文字列 の場所]

Answer (score 0):

既存の DB からリバースエンジニアリングでコンテキストクラスとエンティティクラスを生成しようとしているのだと想像してますが、そうだとするとコマンドが間違ってます。

具体例は以下の記事の「(1) リバースエンジニアリング」を見てください。

スキャフォールディング機能 (CORE)
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2020/03/16/create-controller-and-view-in-aspnet-core-mvc-using-scaffolding.aspx

詳しくは以下の Microsoft のドキュメントを見てください。

スキャフォールディング (リバース エンジニアリング)
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

各パラメータについては、以下の記事の方がまとまっていてわかりやすいかも。

Scaffold-DbContext
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext